# Scaling points to match background. Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, scale, formula

Using some code I found online has helped me create a zoom function for a program I am attempting to make. It is to make a map that allows a user to mark points. Currently the code scales in on the map image alone but I cant get the point icons to realign to where they originally where. I cant workout the maths of it.

Code to zoom in and out

```
if (mev.shiftKey) {
    image.scaleX = Math.max(scaleFactor*image.scaleX, minScale);
    image.scaleY = Math.max(scaleFactor*image.scaleY, minScale);
}

if (mev.ctrlKey) {
    image.scaleX = Math.min(1/scaleFactor*image.scaleX, maxScale);
    image.scaleY = Math.min(1/scaleFactor*image.scaleY, maxScale);
    mat = image.transform.matrix.clone();
    MatrixTransformer.matchInternalPointWithExternal(mat,internalCenter,externalCenter);
    image.transform.matrix=mat;
```

This allows the image to scale up with the following factors

```
    public var scaleFactor:Number = 0.8;
    public var minScale:Number = 0.25;
    public var maxScale:Number = 2.0;
```

The problem occurs when I try to move the pointer icons that are overlaid on this image. They are not to grow or shrink at the moment but they I cant get the maths to get them to move the correct number of pixels away from the mouse location so that they are still in line. Currently I am using the following formulas

```
//decrease zoom
stage.getChildAt(i).x = stage.getChildAt(i).x * scaleFactor;

//increase zoom
stage.getChildAt(i2).x = stage.getChildAt(i2).x / scaleFactor;
```

Any thoughts ? Code I am using came from
http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/zoom/

Comment: You can't apply the factor to the x property directly this will give you wrong results. Instead first you calculate where the x position should be without scaling, then you apply the scale factor, then you set the x property.

Comment: Hello, tried that. I can get the correct position when I place a pin/pointer but when I add the scale factor it doesnt move appropriatly. stage.getChildAt(i).x is the correct position before scaling. Im sure I need a formula in there but cant think of it

Comment: This kind of functionality is very easy and simple to implement since it only involves one factor value. There are well defined static position x and y and scale factor is applied to both and this is the end of it. As an example a well defined position of x:100, y:200 with a scale factor of 0.5 becomes x:50, y:100. There's really nothing that hard about it. You can check if you are scaling correctly by dividing the new x,y position (scaled) by the scale factor, the result should always be the same value.

Comment: The problem is that the user can zoom in anywhere on the map and the scale factor is increasing in a compound manner, I will upload a demo to my server so you can see what it currently does along with the current code to be able to download as the scaling factor and the location of the pins is driving me mad and I cant explain it too well

Comment: The link to the website to see the attempt and source code is here


[link](http://testpage.no-ip.org/mapmaker/proto.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few elements missing from the question like the moving map underneath. Anyway now that it's sorted out ...

If you are not a math genius and can't tackle 2 math formulas at the same time then don't and tackle them one by one then combine them. Once again don't use the x,y property of point for calculation but create specific property (like in a custom class for example). I will name them here origin for convenience.
Given a point with origin property of x:100, y:200, its position on the map is (assuming map is top left coordinate, if not adapt accordingly):

```
point.x = map.x + point.origin.x;
point.y = map.y + point.origin.y;
```

the positioning is solved now you need to solve for scale which is easy:

```
point.x = point.origin.x * scaleFactor;
point.y = point.origin.y * scaleFactor;
```

Both systems are solved now you can combine the two:

```
point.x = map.x + (point.origin.x * scaleFactor);
point.y = map.y + (point.origin.y * scaleFactor);
```